# How to activate GitLab Pages in an existing project?

Tags: java, gitlab, code-coverage, jacoco

I want to publish my code coverage reports for my Java project that is **already** on GitLab. I generate code coverage reports with JaCoCo in a folder located in `app/target/site/jacoco/`.

I saw I had to activate GitLab Pages. But this [link on the GitLab documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/pages/index.html#getting-started) say I have to create a new project. My Java project is **already** in a GitLab Project and I don't know how to do in that case.

Answer (score 6):

**You do not have to create a new project if you already got one**

The GitLab documentation is a little confusing about this. What the documentation means is you can get started with your Pages configuration by using an existing one of another template project. It does not mean you can only use GitLab Pages with new projects.

To use GitLab pages in your project, place a `.gitlab-ci.yml` in the root directory of your repository. Here, you can specify how the content of your GitLab Pages site should be generated and published, e.g.

```
pages:
  stage: deploy
  script:
  - mkdir .public
  - cp -r * .public
  - mv .public public
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - public
  only:
  - master
```

Source: https://about.gitlab.com/2016/04/07/gitlab-pages-setup/#add-gitlab-ci

**TL,DR** The GitLab Pages configuration is defined in your CI/CD configuration file (`.gitlab-ci.yml`). You can add or change this file at any point, not only when you create a new project.

---

**Edit:**
The published static content has to be in the public folder in the root of your project. There is no way around that. However, this is not a problem, you can simply move your stuff there during CI/CD, you do not need to change the repository content itself.

If you want to publish `app/target/site/jacoco`, you can do:

```
pages:
  stage: deploy
  script:
  - mv app/target/site/jacoco/ public
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - public
  only:
  - master
```

Comment: Currently my `gitlab-ci.yml` looks like this : https://pastebin.com/Zu9TiF0T and my html pages are already in a folder on the GitLab. Can I just put the path to my html files `app/target/site/jacoco/` instead of creating a new folder `public` ?

Comment: No, they have to be in `public`. I added information specific to you CI/CD configuration from the pastebin link.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I don't know why but the `mv app/target/site/jacoco/ public` command doesn't do anything. After checking my GitLab repository, there is nothing in `public`. What can be the reasons ?

Comment: There will not be anything in your repository aftwards, but there doesn't have to be. You just need to publish your static files as artifacts to public/. For debugging purposes, you can print your directory contents with a simply `ls` command i.e. is `app/target/site/jacoco/` really where you think it is. What is in `public`after the `mv`command etc.

Comment: The documentation then says that after publication I should go to MyProject -> Settings -> Pages to see the URL for the pages. I see the build set apparently working. I don't see a "Pages" item. Is there some additional step?

Comment: There is no additional step, in fact, you should see *Settings->Pages* for any project, even one without a CI/CD configuration. Not sure what the problem could be, maybe a private GitLab instance where the Pages feature is deactivated explicitly?