# GitLab Pages - activate on an exising project

Tags: gitlab

I'm aware of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55732375/how-to-activate-gitlab-pages-in-an-existing-project) which shows how to amend an existing project's .gitlab-ci.yml to prepare and deploy some content for a Project's Pages.

I see that Job run:

```
Uploading artifacts...
Runtime platform                                    arch=amd64 os=linux pid=4464 revision=de7731dd version=12.1.0
public: found 2 matching files                     
Uploading artifacts to coordinator... ok            id=1968 responseStatus=201 Created token=p2LyB8MW
Job succeeded
```

My problem is not to find the URL to access the pages. We are running our gitlab instance.

The docs say to go to Project -> Settings -> Pages, but I see no such "Pages" setting. I'm on v11.5.3 - could that be the problem? As the build works so nicely I'm thinking that Pages should work on this version.

Comment: You mention `our gitlab instance`. Is this self-hosted? and if so, have you enabled [gitlab pages](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/pages/) on your instance?

Comment: Thanks, this does indeed seem to be the problem. I've asked my admin to make the changes and will confirm once I see the effects.